# Import pandas as pd gives a syntax error "invalid syntax" since two days in all my scripts

Tags: pandas, syntax-error, python-module

Since two days I get the following errors in all my script wherever I am importing pandas :
Example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "session_id.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas\_libs\interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
  File "pandas\_libs\missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion import (
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.pyx", line 14, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz.py", line 78
    `self._name`,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My python version is 3.8.10

I have tried to solve the issue by :

1. upgrading pandas
2. upgrading pip
3. upgrading anaconda

Thanks for your help

Comment: This makes no sense. Try running `pip uninstall python-dateutil` and then `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: @richardec. Just tried that but it doesn't help